# FTPClient upload file from html form

Tags: ftp, inputstream, forms, ftp-client, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to write java code in my servlet to upload, by FTP, a file from a simple html form like this:

```
<form name="fileUpload" method="post" action="StuffService" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="nomeFile" />   
     <input type="submit" value="GO"/>
</form>
```

This form is in a JSP and it is bound with the Servlet 3.0 StuffService (using @MultipartConfig) by doPost() method.

Using library *common-io-2.4* and *common-net-3.2* I create a FTPClient object to upload file on the server:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
...
client.storeFile(...);
```

storeFile method wants name of file and an InputStream.

**How can I get InputStream correctly if the file comes from a HTML form?**

I've tried:

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("nomeFile");
String fileName = getFilename(filePart);
File f = new File(fileName);
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(f);

client.storeFile(fileName, input);
```

but nothing, I got *java.io.FileNotFoundException*. Maybe I need the full path of file but I've read that it is impossible from a html form 'cause security html stuff.

How can I do this?

Thank you and sorry my bad english!
bye

Comment: use `filePart.getInputStream()` instead of `FileInputStream`